# Xcode not recognizing directory structure

Tags: xcode

I've recently downloaded GPUImage which is made up of one large directory containing the framework and various sample projects within it. Usually when I run a project it's simply one folder containing the project and everything works fine. However, when I run one of the sample projects within GPUImage, it's not recognizing the provisioning profile. When I move the sample project out of the GPUImage folder on its own, the provisioning profile error goes away, but then I get a bunch of new errors about it not being able to find the framework and other things (I messed around with moving stuff around but it turned into a disaster).

I'm wondering, is there a path somewhere that I need to change to get Xcode to work like normal when running a sample project from within the GPUImage directory so I don't get the provisioning profile error?

Comment: What, exactly is the provisioning profile error you are getting?

Comment: @SimonGoldeen - Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.sunsetlakesoftware.FilterShowcase' could not be found

Comment: This has nothing to do with the directory structure.  When trying to archive or build and run on device, Xcode looks for a provisioning profile that matches the application's bundle identifier. Without looking at your screen it is kinda hard to figure out the exact issue, but I would suggest Googling that error and trying out some of the solutions you find.

Comment: @SimonGoldeen - Thanks for the responses. I'm usually able to run sample projects from others with no problem. I've compared this sample project from GPUImage with the build settings of other sample projects and they're exactly alike. One odd thing I notice is that when you right click on the Xcode symbol in the dock, this project I'm trying to run never shows up in the list of recently opened apps. That's why I'm thinking it has something to do with the path. But appreciatee it though thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: Very odd.  I just downloaded and successfully built and ran the project.  No idea why you are having code signing issues.

Comment: @SimonGoldeen - I found the problem, it was because I had deleted my team provisioning profile. I had no clue that the team provisioning profile was what was needed to run projects created by other people. I do appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, somewhere along the line I deleted my team provisioning profile! Didn't realize it, but I was also unable to run any other sample projects that weren't created by me.